# How should I create controller in laravel for a model with relation

Tags: php, laravel

I am newbie on laravel and have studied documentation and knowledge concern with laravel. I now can create a complete project using laravel. But I am a little confusion with creating a controller related to a model. For example,
I have a model of User and also UserInformation. I created a resource controller for User model and so I can make CRUD for User. User model has relation like UserInformation. I would like to know is, should I create new controller for UserInformation or should I just need to implement in UserController. Is there any reference for the best practices to laravel project.

Comment: Too broad. As a rule of thumb use same controller, if user will update User and UserInformation from the same GET request (read: url). Of course there are many situations where this rule of thumb does not apply well (like SPA applications). There's no best practice regarding this.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on you requirement. There is no wrong or correct answer here.

Generally if there is going to be more logic around the `UserInformation` model you can use a separate controller like `UserInformationContoller`. If not you can lavarage the same `UserController`

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. :)